# What the most efficient way to compare the content of two lists?

Tags: performance, linq, c#-4.0

Considering the two lists below, what's the best way to compare?

```
var a = new List<string>() { "2016", "2017" };  
var b = new List<string>() { "2017", "2018" };
```

Comment: Are the lists ordered? Memory efficiency or runtime efficiency? (Or both? What's more important?)  Do you need to know if they are different, or complete differences list?

Comment: What kind of comparison result do you need/want?

Comment: @OriNachum independent of the order, runtime efficiency, i need to know if they're different. Thanks :)

Comment: True/false @ErnodeWeerd

Comment: Off my head: First compare sizes, then start a foreach, twice, and break on first difference.

Comment: @OriNachum Or just one `for` loop with an index into the lists, after the length comparison (assuming that differing lengths is also a failure condition).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, I think `for` and `foreach`, are the same efficiency, but yeah. :)

Comment: @OriNachum That's not entirely accurate. In the simple case where the underlying enumerable is an `IList` (and the usage is simple, can't remember the rule specifically), the compiler will actually change a `foreach` into a `for` and avoid allocating the enumerator state machine and some temporary variables in favour of direct array memory access and a counter. Efficiency aside, it stops you from needing two `foreach` calls.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, what do you do in each loop?

Comment: @OriNachum Never mind, not entirely sure we're on the same page. I thought you were saying to fire up a `foreach` for each list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For independent of the order comparison:

```
bool result = a.Count == b.Count && a.Intersect(b).Count() == a.Count;
```

Comment: Straight from the docs: "The `SetEquals` method ignores duplicate entries and the order of elements in the other parameter." So you'd need to understand if those rules are valid for the OP. It seems as though order is not a problem, but duplicates might be (alleviated by hash sets not allowing duplicates perhaps).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth "independent of the order" made me think they are not ordered.

Comment: I know, I commented as much - I'm just adding more information to the answer that a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (But the lists must be ordered and distinct):

```
a.SequenceEqual(b)
```

Thank you guys for the effort! :)

Comment: If the lists are ordered and distinct, you should have specified that in the question. So rather than posting this trivial answer you'd better delete the whole post.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's specified in the comments... :)

Comment: @AndréLuisTosatodaCruz, You said "independent of the order" that means they are not ordered, and distinct wasn't mentioned. ({1,1} != {1})

Comment: @OriNachum in this answer, i said "must be ordered and distinct" just for using this solution, but my main problem didn't need to be ordered.